# Unexpected NaN output after typeof var displays expected numer type

Tags: javascript, nan

Getting an unexpected NaN on an Exercise in Eloquent Javascript chapter 4, but the error is not obvious enough for me to pick up on it. Would someone mind taking a look and pointing out my error?

```
/*
Write a range function that takes two arguments, start and end, and returns an array containing all the numbers from start up to (and including) end.
*/
var numRng = [];
function range( start, end ) {
  //var numRng = [];
  cntr = ( end - start );
  for ( i = 0; i <= cntr; i++ ) {
    numRng.push( start );
    start++;
  } // end FOR
  //return numRng;
} // end FUNC range

range( 1, 10 );
/*for ( i = 0; i < numRng.length; i++ ) {
  console.log( 'Array element ' + numRng.indexOf( 1 + i ) + ' contains range value: ' + numRng[i] );
}*/

/*
Next, write a sum function that takes an array of numbers and returns the sum of these numbers. Run the previous program and see whether it does indeed return 55.
*/
var total = 0;
function sum( numRng ) {
  //var total = 0;
  for ( i = 0; i <= numRng.length; i++ ) {
    //console.log( total );
    total += numRng[i];
    //console.log( total );      
  } // end FOR
  console.log( typeof total );
  console.log( total );      
} // end FUNC range

sum( numRng );
console.log( 'Total sum of all element values held by array numRng is: ' + total );
```

And here is the Firebug output, displaying that `typeof total` after the `for` loop in `func` sum is indeed `number` but is then output as `NaN`.

```
var numRng = []; // seem to require global var ...nt values held by array numRng is: ' + total ); 
number
NaN
Total sum of all element values held by array numRng is: NaN
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `typeof(NaN)` is "number". Check the value of `numRng`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is here

```
for ( i = 0; i <= numRng.length; i++ )
                ^
```

`numRng[numRng.length]` => undefined
I corrected the code below

```js
var numRng = [];
function range( start, end ) {
  //var numRng = [];
  cntr = ( end - start );
  for ( i = 0; i <= cntr; i++ ) {
    numRng.push( start );
    start++;
  } 
} 

range( 1, 10 );


var total = 0;
function sum( numRng ) {
  for ( i = 0; i < numRng.length; i++ ) {
    total += numRng[i]; 
  }
  console.log( typeof total );
  console.log( total );      
}
sum( numRng );
console.log( 'Total sum of all element values held by array numRng is: ' + total );
```

Comment: Ah right I see the problem now: `<=` in the loop of array that starts at 0 ends at `array.length - 1`. So there was an undefined array element being looped over that caused `total` to go NaN I guess. Thanx.

Comment: right. you can use either `<=array.length-1` or `<array.length`

Answer (score 3):

The only error here is that you have

```
for ( i = 0; i <= numRng.length; i++ )
```

Which should be

```
for ( i = 0; i < numRng.length; i++ )
```

The length of an array is the last index + 1; so when using <= in the final iteration of the loop numRng[i] will be undefined, and adding a number to undefined gives you NaN.

Answer (score 0):

*I think my code is one of tne most interesting codes in this theme. This code you can use any step (positive or negative). Also you can use a large number first then a smaller one.*

```
let array = [];
function range (start, end, step) {
if (step === undefined) step=1;

if (start < end) {
    if (step < 0) step = -step;
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
        array.push(i);
    }
} else if (end < start) {
    if (step > 0) step = -step;
    for (let i = start; i >= end; i += step) {
        array.push(i);
    }
}
return array;
}

function sum() {
let total = 0;
for (let a = 0; a<array.length; a++) {
    total += array[a]; 
}
return total;
}
console.log(range(1, 10)) //[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
console.log(range(10, 1, 3)) //[ 10, 7, 4, 1 ]
console.log(sum(range(10, 1, 3)) // 22
```

Comment: I think you should let others be the judge of that ;-)